# How to Stop animation when button is unpressed

Tags: java, android, xml, animation

I want two things to happen when button is pressed
1. Two images should play over and over again, giving it an animated and un static look.
2. A sound in a loop.

And when the button is unpressed and the finger goes up
1. The sound should stop
2. The animation should stop.

The method i am using right now is shown in the code:

```
    package com.example.newanimation;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    AnimationDrawable rocketAnimation;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      ImageView rocketImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
      rocketImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ball_animation);
      rocketAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) rocketImage.getBackground();
    }

    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
      if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        rocketAnimation.start();
        return true;
      }
      return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

}
```

And the XML is like

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:oneshot="false">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ball01" android:duration="200" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ball02" android:duration="200" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ball03" android:duration="200" />
</animation-list>
```

I am keeping  android:oneshot="false">  rather than "true" because i want the animation to play back and forth without stopping till the button is pressed, but i need it to stop when the finger is up from the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `onTouchEvent()`, check for `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` to know that the button has been unpressed.

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
  if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
    if(rocketAnimation.isRunning()){
      rocketAnimation.stop();
    }
  }

  if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
    if(!rocketAnimation.isRunning()){
      rocketAnimation.start();
    }
  }
  return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: The method cancel(); is undefined for Animation Drawable :/

Comment: change it to `stop()` :D

Comment: Bro could you tell me where to get source codes for android apps?

Answer (score 0):

This below code is a perfect solution for your problem.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    AnimationDrawable rocketAnimation;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ImageView rocketImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        rocketImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.roket);
        rocketAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) rocketImage.getBackground();


        button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    rocketAnimation.start();
                    return true;
                } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    rocketAnimation.stop();
                    return false;
                } else
                    return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Check on the video for demo
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=shQ8GOfeJew&feature=youtu.be